# Get all combinations of N items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of items:

```
[0,1,10,20,5,6,7]
```

is there a brief, pythonic way to get all groupings of n variables? In this case, similar groups with a different order are considered duplicates.

```
3:
(0,1,10)
(0,1,20)
(0,2,5)
...

4:
(0,1,10,20)
(0,1,10,5)
(0,1,10,6)
...
```

Comment: `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Are you looking for a dict of list of combinations where dict keys are 1, 2, 3 etc? And any reason you've added `pandas` as a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations([0,1,10,20,5,6,7], 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for ["powerset" from recipes in itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

l = [0,1,10,20,5,6,7]


list(powerset(l))
```

Output:

```
[(),
 (0,),
 (1,),
 (10,),
 (20,),
 (5,),
 (6,),
 (7,),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 20),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (1, 10),
 (1, 20),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (1, 7),
 (10, 20),
 (10, 5),
 (10, 6),
 (10, 7),
 (20, 5),
 (20, 6),
 (20, 7),
 (5, 6),
 (5, 7),
 (6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10),
 (0, 1, 20),
 (0, 1, 5),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 1, 7),
 (0, 10, 20),
 (0, 10, 5),
 (0, 10, 6),
 (0, 10, 7),
 (0, 20, 5),
 (0, 20, 6),
 (0, 20, 7),
 (0, 5, 6),
 (0, 5, 7),
 (0, 6, 7),
 (1, 10, 20),
 (1, 10, 5),
 (1, 10, 6),
 (1, 10, 7),
 (1, 20, 5),
 (1, 20, 6),
 (1, 20, 7),
 (1, 5, 6),
 (1, 5, 7),
 (1, 6, 7),
 (10, 20, 5),
 (10, 20, 6),
 (10, 20, 7),
 (10, 5, 6),
 (10, 5, 7),
 (10, 6, 7),
 (20, 5, 6),
 (20, 5, 7),
 (20, 6, 7),
 (5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 20),
 (0, 1, 10, 5),
 (0, 1, 10, 6),
 (0, 1, 10, 7),
 (0, 1, 20, 5),
 (0, 1, 20, 6),
 (0, 1, 20, 7),
 (0, 1, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 6, 7),
 (0, 10, 20, 5),
 (0, 10, 20, 6),
 (0, 10, 20, 7),
 (0, 10, 5, 6),
 (0, 10, 5, 7),
 (0, 10, 6, 7),
 (0, 20, 5, 6),
 (0, 20, 5, 7),
 (0, 20, 6, 7),
 (0, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 10, 20, 5),
 (1, 10, 20, 6),
 (1, 10, 20, 7),
 (1, 10, 5, 6),
 (1, 10, 5, 7),
 (1, 10, 6, 7),
 (1, 20, 5, 6),
 (1, 20, 5, 7),
 (1, 20, 6, 7),
 (1, 5, 6, 7),
 (10, 20, 5, 6),
 (10, 20, 5, 7),
 (10, 20, 6, 7),
 (10, 5, 6, 7),
 (20, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 5),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 6),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 10, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 20, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 20, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 20, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 10, 20, 5, 6),
 (0, 10, 20, 5, 7),
 (0, 10, 20, 6, 7),
 (0, 10, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 10, 20, 5, 6),
 (1, 10, 20, 5, 7),
 (1, 10, 20, 6, 7),
 (1, 10, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (10, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 10, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 10, 20, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 10, 20, 5, 6, 7)]
```